# AQS syntax when providing a filter for BLE scanning in UWP

Tags: uwp

I have the following working code which filters the devices returned in a UWP app when scanning for Bluetooth Low Energy devices.

```
string[] requestedProperties = { "System.Devices.Aep.DeviceAddress", "System.Devices.Aep.IsConnected", "System.Devices.Aep.Bluetooth.Le.IsConnectable", "System.Devices.Aep.IsPaired" };
var bleAqsFilter = "(System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId:=\"{bb7bb05e-5972-42b5-94fc-76eaa7084d49}\" AND System.ItemNameDisplay:~~\"" + deviceName + "\")";

deviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(bleAqsFilter, requestedProperties, DeviceInformationKind.AssociationEndpoint);
```

I would like to extend my `bleAqsFilter` but I am confused about the Advanced Query Syntax (AQS) used in the second line: `:=` and `:~~`. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711(v=vs.85).aspx) for AQS syntax does not cover these elements. Both syntax elements are used in the article [Enumerate devices over a network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/enumerate-devices-over-a-network).

Where are the AQS syntax elements, including `:=` and `:~~`, explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague provided the answer. The documentation I could not find was this: [Using Advanced Query Syntax Programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb266512(v=vs.85).aspx), and the two bits of syntax I highlighted are defined thus:

> Operator: COP_EQUAL
>   Symbol: =
>   Example: System.FileExtension:=".txt"
>   Description: The value is the string ".txt".
>   […]
>   Operator: COP_VALUE_CONTAINS
>   Symbol: ~~
>   Example: System.Search.Autosummary:~~round
>   Description: Finds all items with an Autosummary that contains the characters round.
>   […]